# Spotify API invalid token access

Tags: java, spotify

I want to get a playlist by id using the Client Credentials Flow.
Even though I can get the `accessToken` and set it properly into the Spotify API object, it's invalid somehow (even after just creating it).
In the Spotify API connection class:

```
private static final SpotifyApi spotifyApi = new SpotifyApi.Builder()
            .setClientId(clientId)
            .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .build();

    public static void clientCredentials_Async() {
        try {
            final ClientCredentialsRequest clientCredentialsRequest = spotifyApi.clientCredentials()
                    .build();

            final CompletableFuture<ClientCredentials> clientCredentialsFuture = clientCredentialsRequest.executeAsync();

            final ClientCredentials clientCredentials = clientCredentialsFuture.join();

            spotifyApi.setAccessToken(clientCredentials.getAccessToken());
            System.out.println(clientCredentials.getAccessToken());

            System.out.println("Expires in: " + clientCredentials.getExpiresIn());
```

until here the code works normally, but when I try to get a playlist by its id (the playlist is not private or has any typo in the id) in:

```
 private static final String playlistId = "5GOQSS6SUFDD6SyMfVRMA5";
   private static final SpotifyApi spotifyApi = SpotifyApiConnection.getSpotifyApi();
   private static final GetPlaylistRequest getPlaylistRequest = spotifyApi.getPlaylist(playlistId)
           .build();


   public static void getPlaylist_Async() {
       try {
           final CompletableFuture<Playlist> playlistFuture = getPlaylistRequest.executeAsync();

           final Playlist playlist = playlistFuture.join();

           System.out.println("Name: " + playlist.getName());
       } catch (CompletionException e) {
           System.out.println("Error: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
       } catch (CancellationException e) {
           System.out.println("Async operation cancelled.");
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       SpotifyApiConnection.clientCredentials_Async(); // Fetch the access token
       getPlaylist_Async();
   }
}
```

I get this output:

> BQAwiNqNEe1lz_wkBFNBEydg4telS29eViMt9KQR-yxZA_cbuqaEEdcTymrVAP-injggJP-3QoUEUBByY6AnJkRQUcmDK-sGKr9IcLlK4e9p-KvwDbA //the access token isn't null as you can see
> Expires in: 3600
> Error: Invalid access token

I'm using this wrapper to access the API https://github.com/spotify-web-api-java/spotify-web-api-java